# How do I enable the block selection button in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to use block selection, but the option to turn it on (Edit->Block Selection) is disabled. Why is it disabled, and how can I enable it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please include more details, including your code, to help us answer this question?

Comment: It is not a code thing, just oracle sql...feature(?). Please check my screenshot. Thanks! https://humormagnate.tistory.com/20

Comment: Which panel has focus when you select the Edit menu? And which version are you using?

Comment: Code editor, and version 18.3.0.277. There is no problem with classmates who are installed together. Should I just reinstall it..?

Comment: Try getting version 19.1

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue "Block Selection" grey out under the Edit menu

 For some reason, you changed somewhere the preference setting


 to solve this problem go to this folder;


C:\Users\ (your name) \AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer

delete the folder that reads the system and a bunch of numbers


please make sure you remember your connection database detail cos once its folder is deleted as well as your favourite shortcut setting

you need to set up a connection, like start over in the beginning

 I hope this works for you!!